# How to determine the target .NET platform version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have opened third party source code using Visual Studio 2010. I can't determine the target version of .NET.

Where can I look it up?

Comment: all the answers below assume you have the project file for the source code.... is it only the source without a project?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the application.

A Web Application, Library, Console App, WPF App, etc, just open the properties of the project, and look on the Application tab. If you don't see an Application tab, chances are it's a Web Site.

[image]

A Web Site (different from Web Application) will use whatever is in the web.config file in conjunction with whatever App Pool you actually run it on in IIS. (look in `system.codedom/compilers` of the web.config). Here is an example targeting the .NET Framework 3.5:

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
          type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
  <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
</compiler>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click a project in the Solution Explorer and go to Properties.

You will see the target .NET framework version on the Application tab:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Project properties and check Application tab